# Regarding daemon thread providing some service to non daemon thread

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have one query that is I have developed a code below of multiple threads named thread one and thread two, below is the code ..

class multip implements Runnable {

```
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        try {


        Thread.sleep(500);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                System.out.println("i");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MultiThread3 {
    public static void main(String... a) {
        multip obj = new multip();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(obj);
        t1.currentThread().setName("one");
        t1.start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(obj);
        t2.currentThread().setName("two");
        t2.start();

    }

}
```

Now I want thread  two be set as daemon thread and it should provide some service to thread one it could be any kind of service but at last What I was trying to achieve is that a daemon thread providing some service to non daemon thread. Please advise how to achieve this.The question is about of how the daemon thread will provide the service to non daemon thread..?

Comment: Folks Please advise for this.

Comment: Ummm `t2.setDaemon(true);`  Am I missing something?

Comment: The question is about of how the daemon thread will provide the service to non daemon thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is about of how the daemon thread will provide the service to non daemon thread

I would use an executor service. If you want to return a value from the daemon thread, you can use a `Callable<ReturnType>` instead of a `Runnable`.

```
// creating a thread pool.
ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new ThreadFactory() {
    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        // creating a thread.
        Thread two = new Thread(r, "two");
        // making it a daemon thread.
        two.setDaemon(true);
        return two;
    }
});

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    // creating a task and submitting it.
    service.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("["+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"] - Hello World.");
            Thread.yield();
        }
    });
service.shutdown();
```

prints

```
[two] - Hello World.
[two] - Hello World.
[two] - Hello World.
```

First it creates a thread pool with a work queue.  The thread pool has a factor which creates threads, in this case with a given name which is a daemon.

Secondly there is a loop which add 10 tasks to the queue for the executors thread(s) to execute.

Finally it stops the service when it has finished with it (this is rarely needed)

Comment: @assylias Sometimes *the real question* is not immediately obvious. ;)

Comment: @peter Awesome man , could you please post the updated code completely as I am going through executor service , thanks in advance.

Comment: @peter could you also please expain what is happeing the above code that is you have posted as I have understood partially

Comment: Ok, added an explanation. If you have specific questions, let me know.

Comment: @Peter but what service it is providing to a non daemon thread , where this is in code ..!!

Comment: @PeterLawrey could you please also put comment in the code for example where it is creating the thread pool

Comment: @PeterLawrey i have used the following link to understand the background concept but please advise in your code where the daemon thread is providing the service to a non daemon thread..?

Answer (score 1):

To make `t1` a daemon for example:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(obj);
t1.setName("one");
t1.setDaemon(true);
t1.start();
```

Note:

- `setDaemon` needs to be called before the thread is started
- `t1.currentThread().setName("one");` most certainly does not do what you want. It sets the name of the main thread to "one", not the name of t1. See my code above for what you probably meant.
- the information can easily be found in the [javadoc of Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) which should be the first place you look at when you search that kind of information.

Comment: The question is about of how the daemon thread will provide the service to non daemon thread.

Comment: @user1538526 A daemon thread is just a thread - the only difference is that the JVM won't wait until a daemon thread finishes when it exits. So you can have a daemon thread execute tasks the same way you would have a non-daemon thread run those same tasks.