# Need to understand the scenario for below piece of code

Tags: java, multithreading

I have below piece of code..

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;

public class daemonTest {

    public static void main(String... a) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService service = Executors
                .newSingleThreadExecutor(new ThreadFactory() { // anonmyous class start
                    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                        Thread two = new Thread(r, "two");
                        two.setDaemon(true);
                        System.out.println("two --->" + two.isDaemon());
                        return two;
                    }
                });
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            service.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("[" + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                            + "] - Hello World.");
                    Thread.yield();
                }
            });
        service.shutdown();
    }
}
```

and the output of the result is ...

```
two --->true
[two] - Hello World.
[two] - Hello World.
[two] - Hello World.
[two] - Hello World.
[two] - Hello World.
[two] - Hello World.
[two] - Hello World.
[two] - Hello World.
[two] - Hello World.
[two] - Hello World.
```

Please advise what the above piece of code is doing..as the thing that I want to achieve is setting one thread as daemon and then that daemon thread will provide the service to the non daemon thread!!

Comment: Well it *looks* like that's already doing what you want. Can you be clearer about what you're really asking?

Comment: Have you looked at the API docs for the classes from java.util.concurrent?-

Comment: You are creating ten threads. There seems to be no difference between the threads - they're created from the same definition of `Runnable` code and wasn't initialized with different variables.

Comment: The code is based on my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665729/regarding-daemon-thread-providing-some-service-to-non-daemon-thread

Answer (score 0):

> Please advise what the above piece of code is doing..

Here's your code:

```
        service.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("[" + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + "] - Hello World.");
                Thread.yield();
            }
        });
```

You are submitting 10 jobs that do `println`, a `yield()` which is extraneous, and then they immediately.  They aren't waiting for any threads.  If you need it to then you need a `two.join()` somewhere in your runnable.

Comment: @Gray..I want thread two be set as daemon thread and it should provide some service to thread one it could be any kind of service but at last What I was trying to achieve is that a daemon thread providing some service to non daemon thread.If you think this not the right approach could you please post the correct code..!!

Comment: I don't understand @user1538526.  You have 2 threads.  One thread you want to process your 10 jobs.  What does the 2nd thread do?  Do you want to fork another thread in each of your 10 jobs?  Do you want to fork another thread once that services all of the 10 jobs?

Comment: it mite be that I may be wrong then please suggest in code terms how would you approach to the solution of this problem , s the thing that I want to achieve is setting one thread as daemon and then that daemon thread will provide the service to the non daemon thread!!

Comment: @user1538526 Take a step back.  Without using the word daemon explain what you are trying to achieve.  1000 foot view please.  You want to process a bunch of jobs.  Each job needs some sort of information from the other thread or something?

Comment: @Gray..I simply want to create two threads and named A and B , then setting B thread as Daemon and after that thread B should provide some service to thread A, if you could please update the code that will become easy for me to understand.

Comment: @Gray You can't `join()` on an ExecutorService you need to use `awaitTermination` A ThreadFactory creates thread(s) so creating a thread there is a natural thing to do.

Comment: I certainly know about the `join()` @Peter but good point about the factory.  I'm confused by what he is asking.