# Daemon thread service utility

Tags: java, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regarding daemon thread providing some service to non daemon thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665729/regarding-daemon-thread-providing-some-service-to-non-daemon-thread)

I want to develop an application in which a daemon thread will provide a service to non daemon thread , I have develop the below code

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;

public class daemonTest {

    public static void main(String... a) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService service = Executors
                .newSingleThreadExecutor(new ThreadFactory() { // anonmyous class start
                    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                        Thread two = new Thread(r, "two");
                        two.setDaemon(true);
                        System.out.println("two --->" + two.isDaemon());
                        return two;
                    }
                });
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            service.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("[" + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                            + "] - Hello World.");
                    Thread.yield();
                }
            });
        service.shutdown();
    }
}
```

But please advise If i create a new thread that is not a daemon thread then how the daemon thread named two will provide the service to newly created thread , at last this I want to achieve

Comment: @pb2q not at all first read the content of this question

Comment: @pb2q this time it is the main thread which is accessing the service

Comment: The code is based on my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665729/regarding-daemon-thread-providing-some-service-to-non-daemon-thread